Remove depot constraint in VRP solved using Google Or-Tools
Hi!
I'm currently working on a particular VRP. The goal is the same as the traditional VRP, which is to minimize the time associated with the longest route. The fundamental difference that is blocking me at the moment is that I need to remove the constraint related to the depot. Each vehicle can start from a different location, and once it has visited the last location of its assigned route, it must return to its starting location (two vehicles cannot depart from the same location).
After several searches on the internet, I found that the recommended solution is to set the distance between the depot and the locations to zero. However, this solution does not solve my problem because it does not result in a closed loop route. Indeed, within the route obtained in this way, the last segment corresponding to the vehicle's return from the last location to the starting one is not taken into account.
Therefore, I would like to ask if it is possible to solve this problem (I'm aware that the computational complexity increases significantly by removing the depot), and if so, how could I achieve the desired result.
Thank you in advance for your attention, and if you can provide any help, I would be infinitely grateful.

My first attempt would be:
Duplicate each location twice:

  A -> A', A''
  B -> B', B''

_' will serve as depot-out node
_'' will serve as depot-in node
(Those are normal nodes and the routing-solver doesn't allow multiple visits -> two copies).

Remove all outgoing-edges of the depot-node, except for _'
  (aka mutate cp-domain of next-var to reduce graph-connectivity).
Remove all ingoing-edges of the depot-node, except for _''.
All edges incident to the depot-node have 0 transit costs and time-accumulation.

Model pickup-delivery semantics for each pair of _' and _'' in this order:
  _' precedes _'' (and is on same tour).

Links:

PD
NextVar


Your idea is correct but I encountered some difficulties. I interpreted your message in this way: from the depot, I can go to any exit node, but not to an entry node. From an exit node, I can only go to an entry node. From an entry node, I can go either to the corresponding exit node or to the depot. Not being an expert in OR-Tools, my idea was to create a distance matrix like the one I leave in the response below (I can't upload images here).

Not quite. Imagine 3 layers: 0: depot, 1: in/out copies, 2: visits. In and out-nodes are not connected. In connects depot and visits from left to right. Out connects depots and visits from right to left. Visits cannot go to depot directly (vice versa). PD handles synch of in/out type.   This is a hard-constraint form. Tricks on dist-mat only are soft-variants where invald configs are costly but feasible.  This might be a problem, especially early when there are no good solutions yet. But soft approaches are surely less problematic in terms of anytime behaviour -> finding something ok quickly.

I'm really sorry, but I still can't understand what you're trying to tell me. I've recently started using OR-Tools to work on my master's thesis. I've tried to imagine what you're trying to say, but I just can't grasp it. How can the nodes in and out not be connected? What should be the path that the vehicle follows? What do you mean by left to right and right to left? If you could be a bit clearer and maybe give me an example, I would appreciate it. If the space available in the comment is too limited, could you please leave another answer? Thank you anyway for the time you've dedicated to me

Tackling this stuff asks you for some own research (which might include how to use StackOverflow). Understanding the approach is linked to basic graph-theory and ortools routing-solver' internal constraint-programming model. If you look up those things, things might get more clear. Hint: the solver assumes a complete-graph of size N and there exists one Next-Variable for each node to describe the successor-node (i even linked it!). CP is about variables (w. domains) and constraints and we can remove valid instantiations from those to make the complete-graph incompl.(sparse) to restrict paths.

The distance matrix that I've created is like the one below. I represent a value that is beyond the maximum distance that vehicles are allowed to travel. 'v' is a value that represents the distance between the exit node and the other entry node.
With this distance matrix, the solver gives me a solution, but usually, it's not the best one. Furthermore, sometimes it gives "no solution found" as a result.
I can't understand what the problem is and if there is a smarter way to achieve the same result that provides a better solution.
Thank you so much for your help.
distance matrix
